# Program for SOV calculation

Tags: proteins, secondary-structure

Are there any programs (web server or installable) out there to calculate segment overlap score (SOV) for protein secondary structures?
Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/nanjiangshu/calSOV

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works!

Comment: Just googled it not sure it calculates the SOV in use today, seems SOV99 to me